# How to make that when clicking on the link the color of the border changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make that when clicking on the link the color of the img div border changed? And the text is returned back to "not selected Click"?

```js
$('.div').click(function() {

  if ( !($(this).hasClass('selected')) ) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $(this.nextElementSibling).text('selected text');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this.nextElementSibling).text('not selected');    
    
  }
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected  <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a> </p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>
```

Comment: Is `$(this.nextElementSibling).html('not selected <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a>'); ` what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a `span` inside the `p` and you change text only of span and you keep the `a`. Then you can show/hide the a.

after that create the same event for the `a` where you target the `div` using `prev()` and you do the same logic (it can be simplified in this case):

```js
$('.div').click(function() {

  if (!($(this).hasClass('selected'))) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this.nextElementSibling).find('span').text('selected text');
    $(this.nextElementSibling).find('a').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this.nextElementSibling).find('span').text('not selected');
    $(this.nextElementSibling).find('a').show();

  }
});
$('a.clicked').click(function() {
  var elem = $(this).parent().prev();
  elem.addClass('selected');
  elem.next().find('span').text('selected text');
  elem.next().find('a').hide();

});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p"><span>not selected</span> <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a> </p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p"><span>not selected</span> <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p"><span>not selected</span> <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick solution based on what you are already using. The link is embedded in the `p` so you have to use `parent()`, and `prev()` is the jQuery equivalent to `nextElementSibling` and returns a jQuery object.

You can notice that i used `$('body').on('click', 'a.clicked', function)` instead of `$('a.clicked').click(function)`, it is in case you wan to add again a link in the text dynamically. With `click`, only the ones already present at page loding will be targeted. With `on('click')`, dynamically created elements will too.

As a note, your solution relies on elements position, which is maybe not the safest way to do. Using a wrapper with a class to access all elements from classes would be a bit better.

```js
$('.div').click(function() {

  if ( !($(this).hasClass('selected')) ) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $(this.nextElementSibling).text('selected text');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this.nextElementSibling).text('not selected');    
    
  }
});

$('body').on('click', 'a.clicked', function(e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if ( !($(this).parent().prev().hasClass('selected')) ) {
      $(this).parent().prev().addClass('selected');
      $(this).parent().text('selected text');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().text('not selected');    
    
  }
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected  <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a> </p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector for this

```
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.div-class:active {
  border-color: red;
}
```

If you are using scss, you make the css much more clean

```
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:active {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the limitations of the existing html structure:

1. the DOM will need to be traversed *up* to the containing (parent)
   element using the `.parent()` method <sup>[Ref jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)</sup>,
2. then *stepping one element back*, from the containing (parent)
   element, using the `.prev()` method <sup>[Ref jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)</sup>, as
   demonstrated in the code snippet embedded below...

*Note:* in addition, the `.next()` method <sup>[Ref jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/next/)</sup> has been used as a replacement to the vanilla javascript `.nextElementSibling` read-only property.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
$('.div').click(function() {

  if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).next().text('selected text');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).next().text('not selected');
  }

});

$('.clicked').click(function() {

  if (!$(this).parent().prev('.div').hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).parent().prev('.div').addClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().text('selected text');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().text('not selected');
  }

});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p">not selected <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p">not selected <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p">not selected <a href="#" class="clicked">Click</a></p>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278544/how-to-make-that-when-clicking-on-the-link-the-color-of-the-border-changed#
```